# Bootstrap CSS table-striped not working with knockout if binding

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, knockout.js

Let's say I have the following table that works with bootstrap css and knockout:

```
<table  style="cursor:pointer;" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover table-condensed">
   <tbody data-bind="foreach: items">
         <tr>
            <td data-bind="text: name"></td>
         </tr>
         <tr data-bind="if: somecondition">
             <td>test</td>
         </tr>
   </tbody>

</table>
```

Now if I set `"somecondition"` to return `"true"`, I can see the result table has the zebra striping. Everything is fine. But if I change the condition to "false", obviously the row disappears from the screen, but I don't see any alternating row color at all. Anybody knows why and how I can make the alternating row color shown?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the Knockout [`if` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) doesn't control whether the element it's *on* will exist or not, just whether that element's *content* will exist or not. (This isn't as clear from the documentation as it might be, but it *is* there, mostly in the *"Note: Using “if” without a container element"* bit). So the `if` in your example will control whether the *content* of the `tr` is present, but the `tr` will be there regardless, giving you a `tr` with absolutely nothing in it, which counts as part of the `:nth-child` work that the Bootstrap striping does but not occupying any vertical space. (You can see this by rendering the page, then right-clicking the table and using "Inspect element" in any modern browser to look at what's actually in the DOM.)

To make the entire row exist/not exist based on the condition, wrap the row with a KO [virtual element](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings-for-virtual-elements.html):

```
<!-- ko: if: somecondition -->
<tr>
    <td>test</td>
</tr>
<!-- /ko -->
```

Example of your original code, not striping correctly: http://jsbin.com/tupusemu/1

Example using a virtual element, striping correctly: http://jsbin.com/tupusemu/2

Answer (score -2):

Just simply remove **tbody** tag from your table it will smoothly work..